# Login to google calendar using token only

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I integrate google calendar with my application successfully.
First time, i authenticate successfully and all the events are created on google calendar properly.

Now, second time i don't want to authenticate, i just want to click on a button then the all the new events from my application should be created on google calendar.

I guess that it will be done by the refresh token.
I received token.
See my below code for that.

```
<?php
session_start();        
require_once('vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/autoload.php');
require_once 'vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php';



$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";   

$client_id = '';
$Email_address = '';     
$key_file_location = ''; 
$client_secret = "";    
$redirect_uri = "";
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setAccessType('offline');   // Gets us our refreshtoken

$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'));

$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(    
$Email_address,      
array($scopes),     
$key         
);      
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
$client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred); 
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
echo "Token".$_SESSION['token'];
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
 $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
 $events = $service->events->listEvents('primary');
 while(true) {

foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {

echo $event->getSummary() . " ==> ";
echo $event->end->dateTime;
echo "<br>";
}
$pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
if ($pageToken) {
$optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
$events = $service->events->listEvents('primary', $optParams);
} else {
break;
}
}
}  


?>
```

I got token here, but now i want to login in my google calendar without using authentication again and again. Because first time i did it.

Now, can i login in my google account using token?
if yes, then how can i do it?

First time i authenticate the user, for that here is my code.

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setApplicationName("ABC-APP");
 $client->setClientId("");
 $client->setClientSecret('');
 $client->setRedirectUri('');
 $client->setScopes(array(
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
 ));
 if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
 $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
 $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
 if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
 }
 }

 if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
        'summary' => "Myevent",
        'location' => "31 Shuijd",
        'description' => "Test Descriptionj",
        'start' => array(
          'dateTime' => "12/1/2016",
          'timeZone' => "Asia/Kolkata",
        ),
        'end' => array(
          'dateTime' => "12/2/2016",
          'timeZone' => "Asia/Kolkata",
        ),
        'recurrence' => array(
          'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
        ),
        'attendees' => array(
          array('email' => $row['contact_email']),
        ),
        'reminders' => array(
          'useDefault' => FALSE,
          'overrides' => array(
            array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
            array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
          ),
        ),
      ));
    $event = $service->events->insert("primary", $event);


 } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're headed in a good direction. You just need to refresh your access token when it has expired, using the refresh token received from Google after setting the access type `offline`. You should have that refresh token saved in the database for each user that grants you offline access, so you can refresh the access token without asking them for permission again.

The code would look something like this:

```
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
$tokens = $client->getAccessToken();
$tokens->refresh_token = $refreshToken; // the refresh token is not returned, so if you're updating the session or database, you should set it manually so you don't lose it
```

Comment: Do you have any sample code ? i dont have any idea about it.

Comment: I've implemented it for gmail in this wrapper https://packagist.org/packages/adevait/gmail-wrapper, the process is the same. Check the includes/auth.php file. That's basically it - if your access token has expired, you call the `refreshToken` function and get the access token again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store access token into session when you login first time 
and pass this when you want to create event if require

```
$session_token = <access token store in session >
if (!$client->getAccessToken()) {
     $client->setAccessToken($session_token);
}
```

Edit :: changes

```
 if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
     $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
     $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
 }

 if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
 }
```

Comment: I have already done this.
Now i want to create all the new events without using autnetication. Because firsttime i authenticate already. Second time i dont need authenticate the user. i just want to use refresh token.

Comment: Token is allowed only for one hour. 
Then it will expires. Then we have to refresh the token, but i dont have any idea how to use it.

Comment: @harishmahajan are you talking $_SESSION['token'] token expires or what ?

Comment: suppose i authenticate the user, i recived token and stored it in  $_SESSION['token'], now in future i want to create all the events to google calendat at that time i dont need to authenticate that user, i just click on a button then all the new events will be created on google calendar. so i think i have to use refresh token for that. but i dont any idea about it. how to use it?

Answer (score -1):

I integrate google calendar with my application successfully. First time, i authenticate successfully and all the events are created on google calendar properly.
->**please attach the code when you have created events for the first time**

Comment: You've got token for the first time. same procedure you have followed for second time. so just try that token and add the event. not tested but it should work.